# Slack im.open returns null

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I apologize for my lack of understanding, but I'm using the slack method `im.open` to grab a direct message channel ID for a small project.

```
web.im.open({token: process.env.botOath, user: userID}, function(res){
     console.log(res.channel.id);
});
```

Unfortunately, the channel ID is returned as 'null'. Is this the proper way to use this method, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an error occured? please post the whole response from Slack, e.g. the content of res

Comment: Is the res object undefined also?

Comment: No, the res object is defined. I get this response:
 { ok: true,

  no_op: true,

  already_open: true,

  channel: { id: 'DBHRGR0RF' },

  scopes: [ 'identify', 'bot:basic' ],

  acceptedScopes: [ 'im:write', 'post' ] } 

I guess an error just occurred somewhere? I'm getting the response I want now...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot **s** at the end of `user => users: userID`